# TableView height change in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to find a way of making the height of a UITableView change depending on how many rows are in the table being displayed.

I've gone through the site for previous questions but none really come to any conclusion.

Language being used is Swift on iOS 8.

Thanks,
Anthony

Comment: This is a UITableView that doesn't fill the screen? Have you tried adding constraints programmatically? You can also adjust the height of the cells.

Comment: I've tried various methods but can't seem to set the UITableView to expand horizontally only when needed.

Comment: Horizontally? Your question asks about changing the height (i.e. vertically)

Comment: Sorry I meant vertically. I would show you via screenshots but I've only just joined so don't have the rep.

Comment: Why don't you want your table view to fill the screen?

Comment: It's essentially just to have the UITableView part of the view change it's size vertically depending on how many rows there are in it. The content under the table would be pinned to the bottom of the table.

Comment: The table view will automatically expand to fit the rows it needs to show. If you need to pin anything to the bottom of the table you can use `tableFooterView`.

Comment: The view is going to be used as a order form. I want to table part to only take up what it needs to and have all the totals directly below it. I just don't want a large space and thought there would be a way of programmatically changing the UITableView to be as tall as the cells it was showing.

Comment: Use `tableFooterView`. It will appear right after the last row, not at the bottom of the screen. Please edit your question to fill in some of the details we've discussed here in the comments.

Comment: If you want to change the table's size, you can adjust its `frame` property, or use an auto-layout height constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `tableFooterView` to pin content to the bottom of a `UITableView`

**EDIT:**
The tableFooterView (and tableHederView) can be modified directly in Interface Builder by dragging a view below (or above) the prototype cell(s) in your table view.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do this within the IB. The way around it was to drag a new view underneath the prototype cell that was already showing in the IB. Then I could change the size to suit my footer content and then just add the footer parts of the layout to that new view within the Table View.

Comment: That's the tableFooterView; Good point, ought to have mentioned it can be done in IB, although your original question didn't mention IB.